# Random integer with random.randint without certain number

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a random number.

```
import random
print(random.randint(1,10))
```

Would I be able to generate a number between 1-10 but without ever generating x?

For example x = 3

Comment: use an if else statement to check if the random number == x and if it is just call random.randint again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three approaches:

1. Loop until it's valid:

   ```
   while (val := random.randint(1, 10)) == 3:  # Python 3.8+, pre-3.8 is more verbose
       pass
   print(val)
   ```
2. Generate from a smaller range, then increment all numbers equal to or higher than the excluded value:

   ```
   val = random.randint(1, 9)
   if val >= 3:
       val += 1
   print(val)
   ```
3. Create a sequence of the numbers you allow, and use `random.choice` (probably the best solution if you're doing this many times; make the sequence once, then reuse it after):

   ```
   # Done once (must convert back to sequence from set, choice only works with sequences)
   values = tuple(set(range(1, 11)) - {3})

   # Done as often as you like
   print(random.choice(values))
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Onliner, using `range` and `sets`:

```
x = 3
print(random.choice(list(set(range(1,11))-{x})))
# list(set(range(1,11))-{x})) -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use choice you can provide a list of acceptable values:

`random.choice([[1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9]])`